# How to add an UIImage above UITableView

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview, ios8, uiimageview

Can anyone please tell me how to add an UIImageView above UITableView?

I have tried adding refresh control custom view still I am not able to get the exact thing which I wanted.

For example check the LinkedIn iOS App's side bar and try to pull down the content in side bar. Please check the link and see the LinkedIn logo in the image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpAjL.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways you do this based on your requirement:

1. If you want to add have the image view always showing on top of the table view. If you are looking for this then please implement below method and return your image view added into a UIView for section 0.

   - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)iSection
2. If you want image view to be hidden on table view load and show it on pull down of the table.

For #2, add your image view with frame having Y value (0 - height of the view). Then adjust the contentInset of your scroll view.

Comment: Thanks Abhinav. It helped.
Actually I was looking for the second option.